# print value of void pointer

Tags: c, pointers

This is the fig11.3 in book **Advanced programming in the UNIX Environment**

```
#include <pthread.h>

#include "apue.h"

void* thr_fn1(void* arg) {
    printf("thread 1 returning\n");
    return ((void*)1);
}

void* thr_fn2(void* arg) {
    printf("thread 2 exiting\n");
    pthread_exit((void*)2);
}

int main(void) {
    int err;
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    void* tret;

    err = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thr_fn1, NULL);
    if (err != 0) err_exit(err, "can't create thread 1");
    err = pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, thr_fn2, NULL);
    if (err != 0) err_exit(err, "can't create thread 2");

    err = pthread_join(tid1, &tret);
    if (err != 0) err_exit(err, "can't join with thread 1");
    printf("thread 1 exit code %ld\n", (long)tret);

    err = pthread_join(tid2, &tret);
    if (err != 0) err_exit(err, "can't join with thread 2");
    printf("thread 2 exit code %ld\n", (long)tret);
    exit(0);
}
```

I was confused that why I cannot typecast void pointer to pointer to long and dereference it

```
printf("thread 1 exit code %ld\n", *(long *)tret);
```

why can we typecast tret to long and get the correct value we want here

```
printf("thread 1 exit code %ld\n", (long)tret);
```

what's the type of tret here?

I show the easy case from GeeksforGeeks to print the value of void pointer below

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int a = 10; 
    void *ptr = &a; 
    printf("%d", *(int *)ptr); 
    return 0; 
}
```

What's difference between two code above?

Comment: It seems like this code is assuming that pointers and longs will have the same size, which isn't necessarily true. I'm also not sure what the point of making it a `void *` is if it's just storing an exit code.

Comment: the secure way is to do `printf("thread 1 exit code %p\n", tret);`, the code you have does assumption whose can be false

Comment: @Aplet123 they use pointers because that's simply what a thread function is supposed to return. The signature is defined and you cannot change it. A cleaner way would be to provide a proper address to the thread where the result can be stored after terminating. Providing `NULL` and storing integers in pointers is a bit ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was confused that why I cannot typecast void pointer to pointer to long and dereference it
>
> ```
> printf("thread 1 exit code %ld\n", *(long *)tret);
> ```

if you do that you dereference the address, but that address is 1 or 2 whose are very probably an invalid address, and even there are not you cannot make supposition of what they contain.

> why can we typecast tret to long and get the correct value we want here
>
> ```
> printf("thread 1 exit code %ld\n", (long)tret);
> ```
>
> what's the type of tret here?

*tret* is a `void *`, and your *thr_f<n>* return a `void *`too,  so the right way to do is :

```
printf("thread 1 exit code %p\n", tret);
```

else you suppose `long` and `void*` have the same size

Answer (score 2):

I think that's because according to the manual of pthread_join, it stores the return value of the thread, not a memory address: as you can see on the thr_fn1 and 2 functions, the return value is (void *)1 and (void *)2.

Dereferencing the pointer is pointless, as we are interested in his value, not the address he points to.

The second case uses this technique because ptr is actually a memory address.